# Different WHERE clauses depending on table schema

Tags: python, mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm trying to make a mysql dump for a database using the "mysqldump" command line tool and I'm looking to do something kind of unique. Essentially, if the table contains a certain column, dump according to those constraints, otherwise, dump the whole table. But due to the nature of the mysqldump command line options, this all has to be in one WHERE clause.

In psuedo code this is what I have to do:

```
if table.columns contains "user_id":
    where = "user_id=1" // dump rows where user_id=1
else:
    where = "TRUE" // dump whole table
```

But in all one where clause that will apply to every table mysqldump comes across

Answer (score 1):

The `--where` option for mysqldump can be used to pass an expression to the SELECT for each table, but it passes the *same* expression to *all* tables.

If you need to use different WHERE clauses for different subsets of tables, you'll need to do more than one mysqldump command, and execute each command against a different set of tables

---

Re your comment:

No, the references to columns in an SQL query must be fixed at the time the query is parsed, and that means any column references must refer to columns that exist in the table. There's no way to make an expression in SQL that uses columns if they do exist and ignores the column reference if the column doesn't exist.

To do what you're describing, you would have to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to see what columns exist in the table, and then format the SQL query for the dump conditionally, based on the columns you find do exist in the table.

But in mysqldump, you don't have the opportunity to do that. It would have to be implemented in the code for mysqldump.

Feel free to get the source code for mysqldump and add your own logic to it. Seems like a lot of work though.

Comment: Okay so I understand that. My question is it possible to design the WHERE clause in such a way that it can apply to any table it comes across?

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks Bill!